# ReactJS + Redux: How to use Mozilla File API to select local image and upload it to web?

Tags: javascript, html, redux, reactjs

I want to have a button and once it is clicked, it opens up the local directory and allow the user to choose an image. Once chosen, I want to store that directory source address and pass it into the src of `<img src=""/>`to display it.

I am trying to use the following to achieve that: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

The HTML of it is:

```
export default class fileUploader extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" style="display:none" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)"/>
        <a href="#" id="fileSelect">Select some files</a>
        <div id="fileList">
          <p>No files selected!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and the JS is:

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
    fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem"),
    fileList = document.getElementById("fileList");

fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (fileElem) {
    fileElem.click();
  }
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
}, false);

function handleFiles(files) {
  if (!files.length) {

    fileList.innerHTML = "<p>No files selected!</p>";

  } else {

    fileList.innerHTML = "";
    var list = document.createElement("ul");
    fileList.appendChild(list);

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      list.appendChild(li);

      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
      img.height = 60;
      img.onload = function() {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
      }

      console.log(img.height)

      li.appendChild(img);
      var info = document.createElement("span");
      info.innerHTML = files[i].name + ": " + files[i].size + " bytes";
      li.appendChild(info);
    }
  }
}
```

For `<input ...>` for HTML I am getting an error: `Unterminated JSX contents`. What may be the issue? I tried add / for `<input.../>` yet it still throws up an error.

Also, how should I go about revising the JS to just be able to select one image file and pass that directory source address to src of `<img/>`?

Comment: Why are you manually creating DOM Elements while using React?

Comment: @Dodekeract Could you guide me? Still learning React at the moment. Why isn't the <input...> catching an error in the first place?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html) is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

What Dodekeract is saying is that you don't want to use direct DOM manipulation such as `document.getElementById` when using React.  React works with a virtual DOM and handles the actual DOM interactions for you, which is why it's so fast. There's some magic there that's definitely worth learning more about at some point.  You generally need to do things the React way, using props and state to write to the virtual DOM in your render function.

Your component should look something like this (untested):

```
class FileUploader extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.state = { file: false };
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({ file: e.target.value });
    }

    render(){
        const image = (this.state.file) ? <img src={this.state.file} /> : null;

        return(
            <div>
                <input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*"  onChange={this.handleChange} style={{ display: 'none' }} />
                <a href="#" id="fileSelect">
                   <label htmlFor="fileElem">Select some files</label>
                </a>
                <div id="fileList">
                    {image}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

It's conventional to give a component a capital first letter, hence "FileUploader".